The meaning of 'charges' in the context

Domestication had long-range consequences for the animals themselves; the very
nature of the animals changed throughout the process — typically not in the
animals’ favor. Through domestication, once-wild animals become increasingly
more dependent on humans, physically and emotionally. Because a handful of traits
(such as curiosity, lack of fear, willingness to try new things, food begging,
submissiveness, etc.) found among the juveniles of a species are those selected in
domestication, the physical traits of the young (shorter faces, excess fat, smaller
brains, smaller teeth, etc.) will also be selected. This leads to modern domesticates
that are physically and behaviorally unable to live independently and that are, in
fact, perpetual juveniles. Once humans began selectively breeding their animal
charges to emphasize or discourage certain physical or behavioral traits, the animals
changed even further. Today, domesticates are, for the most part, smaller (yet
fleshier), more brightly colored, with shorter faces, and rounder skulls. In addition,
domestication has resulted in a permanent loss of genetic diversity within the
species.

What's the exact menaing of the word 'charges'?

It's the animals in their charge (the animals they look after, that they're charged with supervising, keeping safe). More often used of children.

... charge - full OED definition II.10.c (1596–) A person (typically a child), animal, or thing entrusted to someone's care.

Please edit to show that you've looked up "charge" (noun) in a dictionary, what you found, and what questions remain. Right now the only answer is to point you to the dictionary, but you might have new questions after checking it that would get you better answers. Voting to close and downvoting.

@AndyBonner I looked up the dictionary and didn't get the correct answer because I am not a native speaker of English.

Thanks; please edit the question to mention that. For the best results, I suggest mentioning which dictionary, if possible, quote or summarize the results you found that don't seem like the correct answer. For instance, it might be that one of them was relevant but that wasn't clear. An answer about that would be more useful to you than a simple one.

It's not surprising you didn't find it; Merriam-Webster gives about 50 usages and only one is this one!

What Merriam-Webster does say is that a charge is “a person or thing committed into the care of another.” One can scan even large definitions in a dictionary and find the one that makes sense in one’s context.
